# Is there a way to find value for a common column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

For example, I have a category called `Customer_Id`. As few customers have made multiple transactions so for such customers, the customer ID repeats every time they make a transaction. I want to find how many customers have greater than 10 transactions with us based on the number of times the customer ID has repeated. Any suggestions for the query?

Comment: use `GROUP BY` query

Answer (score 0):

You can use count or sum(1) along with group by.

```
Select Sum(1) as TotalTransactions, Customer_Id from transactions group by CustomerId
```

And to apply criteria on aggregate functions, you can use HAVING clause.

```
Select Sum(1) as TotalTransactions, Customer_Id from transactions group by CustomerId HAVING Sum(1) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT employee_id, Count(1) 
FROM transections
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING Count(*) > 10
```